# How to download MS-word file in java?

Tags: java

```
String fileName="raj.doc";
ServletOutputStream stream=null;
BufferedInputStream buf=null;
stream=res.getOutputStream();
String s1=getServletContext().getRealPath("/web-inf/lib/raj.doc");
File doc=new File(s1);

res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-word");
res.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename= "+fileName);
res.setContentLength((int)doc.length());
FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(doc);
buf=new BufferedInputStream(input);
int readBytes=0;
while((readBytes=buf.read())!=-1)
stream.write(readBytes);
```

Give me an example of downloading MS-word file in java. Tell me jar files which are needed.

Comment: Do you want to *download* a file from a server, or *read* a file you already have? If the latter, check out [Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: I have predefined template. I want to download that template in MS-word type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any jars if you want to only download the file and not work with it.
Just use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) code and replace the URL with the URL of your document. Then you should be able to create a new File and just feed everything you read from the URL in the outputstream of the file.